# how to change the path of the preference files in PL/SQL Developer version 9

Tags: plsqldeveloper

my pl/sql developer give me an error (file access denied) every time I execute a sql statement in sql window.  it is running fine in command window.  when I look in support info I notice the Preference files are located as follow

Preference Files

C:\Program Files\PLSQL Developer\Preferences\Default\Default.ini
C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Preferences\USER\default.ini

and I don't have access to this file hence I got the error.
C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Preferences\USER\default.ini

is there a way to change the path to

C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\PLSQL Developer\Preferences\USER\Default.ini

thanks inadvance

Tuan

Answer (score 0):

There is a `prefpath` command-line argument, so you can start PL/SQL Developer using something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PLSQLDeveloper\plsqldev.exe" userid=un/pw@svc prefpath="%APPDATA%\Preferences"
```